# Type script definition for rows and columns of Quasar QTable

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if there is a typescript definition for rows and columns of Qtable ?
Thanks in advance
marnold

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `QTableProps['columns']` and `QTableProps['rows']`.

```
const columns: QTableProps['columns'] = [
  {
    name: 'number',
    align: 'center',
    label: 'ID',
    field: 'number',
    sortable: true,
  }
];
```

```
const rows: QTableProps['rows'] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159}
];
```

Comment: It works! Do not forget to import the type using `import { QTableProps } from 'quasar';`

Answer (score 0):

If you want even more type safety, you can use `QTableColumn`. It will type the `field` and `format` properties for columns correctly.

```js
interface MyRow {
  _id: string,
  date: string,
  foo: number
}
const rows: MyRow[] = [...]

const columns: QTableColumn<MyRow>[] = [{
  field: 'foo', // typesafety here
  format: (val, row) => ... // typesafety for row. It is of type MyRow
  // ...
}]
```